# Google Sheets - Sum numbers inserted by IF statement in SUMIF function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I have a basic SUMIF statement in Google Sheets:

```
=SUMIF(E:E,U5,G:G)
```

This works perfectly and sums correctly if I input the numbers in Column G manually

However Column G actually is all if statements like so:

```
=IF(LEN(F5)>1,"301.95","0.00")
```

And so the SUMIF function always returns 0

How can I get the SUMIF function to sum the output of the IF function and not count it as a 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*remove the **double quotes** `301.95` around numbers (in Column_G formula), its converting them to text which is resulting in the error!*